# Get next monday date in PHP (including today)

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am creating a PHP page that based on a date, will get the date of the next Monday.

A snippet of my code is below - I am obtaining the next monday date using the DateTime and modify methods, but what I need to include is that if today's date is Monday, I want to select that (as it is only selecting the next monday, not including today.

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
$startDate->modify('next monday')->format('d-m-Y');
```

How can I change this so that if today is a Monday, it uses today's date and not the next Monday after it?

Comment: use an if case, where you check if today is monday (i.e. `date('N')` or similar) and print the date according the selected date

Comment: Thank you Raphael, I chose to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

With [date();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you can get the number of the day (ex : 1 for monday) and you can use mktime for specifie a timestamp

Example for get the number of the current day :

```
echo date('N'); // show : 5 cause we are Friday when you post your question
```

Example (from the doc) for date + mktime :

```
// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

So, you can do something like that :

```
// Cause we are the 08/04/2016, this line print 6 (cause tomorow is the 6th day of the week) 
echo date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date(d)+1, date('Y')));
```

If you can get the number of the current day, you can (with a little mathematics) find the next monday.

Use/handle/train this functions and come back if you need more help :).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the posts, I chose to take the approach of getting the number of the day using `$day = $startDate->format('N');` and then creating an if statement to check if the number equals 1.